# CakePHP Media Plugin Helper problem

Tags: cakephp, plugins, helper

I am trying to display an uploaded image with the Media Plugin of CakePHP.

I added the helper to the controller helper array: `var $helpers = array('Media.Media');`. Then, in my view, I have this code: `echo $media−>file($news['Attachment'][0]['dirname'].DS.$news['Attachment'][0]['basename']);`. But the problem is that, it outputs this error:

```
Undefined variable: media− [APP/views/news/view.ctp, line 3]
```

What could be the problem?

By the way, if a plugin has a model User in app/plugin/users/models/user.php and i create a new model called User in the app/models folder which one will be loaded?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off if you are using 1.3.x refer to helpers via $this->HelperName->method(), there could be a variable called $media being set in some method. you can check this by doing var_dump($media);

The other option is that something has maybe unset it. Its very strange that you have the helper set but the variable is not set. It could also be due to adding the $helpers array to the wrong controller, you can try add it to app_controller and see if that works. if it does you had it in the wrong place.

If i got your second question correct, and we are talking about auto loading, a plugin controller will first look for the model in its own plugin directory, if it is not found there it will fall back to the app/models directory.

if you are loading it manually via the $uses array, it depends on the version of cake and how you do it. In previous versions 1.x even $uses = array('User'); would load the plugin model as  cake would auto add the plugin prefix. This has changed for 2.0 afaik.

For other methods of loading a model, such as $this->loadModel('User); would load from app/models and $this->loadModel('PluginName.User') would load from the app/plugins/plugin_name/models dir.

Edit:
you are right that is funny having the error show $media- and there is the problem. did you copy that code from some site? − is not - you have a utf8 char in the code which is what its complaining about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, none of your solutions work. If I use `$this->Media->file()` I get the following error: `Undefined property: View::$Media− [APP/views/news/view.ctp, line 3]`. Adding the Helper to AppController produces the same result. If I `debug($media)`, it shows me a full array, so it is set. Any other suggestions? Regarding my second question, you got it right and I thank you for clarifying that issue.

Comment: Are plugin helpers used the same as normal helpers? I mean, shouldn't it be used as `$this->MediaMedia` or `$this->Media_Media`?

Comment: no, they are loaded differently hence var $helpers = array('Media.Media'); for plugins and var $helpers = array('Media'); for a non plugin.

Comment: with regards to the first issue, $this->Media should be an object (or $media) not a array. make a past of the contents of the variable

Comment: My mistake, it's an object. It contains (part only, as it is too long): `MediaHelper Object
(
    [helpers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Html
        )

    [tags] => Array
        (
            [audio] => %s%s
            [video] => %s%s
            [source] => 
            [object] => %s%s
            [param] => 
        )
`

Comment: Regarding the other question, I asked if using the helpers differs, not declaring them. Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: it seems you have it correct or cake would spit out an error var $helpers = array('Media.Media'); is correct for a helper called MediaHelper in app/plugins/media/views/helpers/media.php

Comment: OK. These being said, what could possibly be the problem for the helper not to function? It seems very weird to me...

Comment: no clue, it is obviously loading the helper or cake would complain, but its not there. try update cake libs to the latest and clear the cache. if that does not work you will have to get your hands dirty in the core and figure it out.

Comment: Looking over and over again, I noticed something: `View::$Media−`. Why is that `-` after the property? Usually, there is no hyphen after it. Could that mean something?

Comment: It could be, but where should I look for something unusual in the code? I got the plugin from Github and haven't changed nothing but the config; I haven't touched the Helper file. Also, I am declaring and using the Helper as I should.

Comment: its the -> in $media->method()

Comment: This is how I call that method: `<?php echo $this->Media−>file($news['Attachment'][0]['dirname'].DS.$news['Attachment'][0]['basename']); ?>`. What could be wrong here?

Comment: omg... − and - is not the same.... delete that whole line and type it out manually from scratch

Comment: OMG...I didn't notice that hyphen...How could it possibly appear there? Oh, never mind, spent almost one day with this problem and couldn't resolve it if it weren't you...Thank you very much again!

Comment: just read the edit i made to my answer last night... its all there. you can mark as solved then :)